# os.Args reads only some data that's been given while running the file in golang

Tags: go

My Program:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    inputs := os.Args[1:]
    log.Print(inputs)
}
```

When run with the command

```
go run filename.go 3001-3005 1->A,2->B,3->C,4->D,5->E
```

gives the output as `[3001-3005 1-,2-,3-,4-,5-]` instead of `[3001-3005 1->A,2->B,3->C,4->D,5->E]`

Comment: Do you also have one or more mysterious files called one or more of A,B,C,D,E sitting in your current directory? On most systems a ">" on the command line has a special meaning: "send output to this file rather than to the console"...

Comment: Yes, Whenever I run this File a file with name E is being created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ">" characters on your command line are being interpreted as *redirections* meaning "send output to a file rather than to the console".

You should be able to stop this happening by quoting the command-line arguments in question. Exactly how you should do this depends on what OS you're on, what shell you're using if you're on a Unix-like OS, etc, but I would try putting double-quotes around that second argument, like this:

```
go run filename.go 3001-3005 "1->A,2->B,3->C,4->D,5->E"
```